# Redirect to another page in Spring if Exception occurs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpresponse, redirect

In spring if there is any exception or error (like 404) its printed on browser. I want to redirect user to some page and log this errors in log file instead of displaying on browser screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/

Answer (score 0):

To log the errors you to use log4j,

[see here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm) and more info

And for error handling ,

[This tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/) is effective

Hope this helps !